# Cargar departamentos según usuarios con array y foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, array, foreach

Quiero guardar un array de múltiples filas, cada departamento puede tener varios usuarios, pero cuando guarda los datos inserta todos los usuarios con el mismo departamento, los valores de project_id, deberían ser diferentes, varios usuarios podrían pertenecer a un mismo departamento pero no todos, ya que existen otros departamentos, este es el código que tengo.

```js
$name = $_POST['name'];
$descripcion = $_POST['description'];

$row_data = array();

foreach($_POST['user_id'] as $row => $user_id) {
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $descripcion);
  $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['user_id'][$row]));
  foreach($_POST['project_id'] as $row1 => $profile_id) {
    $project_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['project_id'][$row1]));
  }
  $row_data[] = "('$name', '$descripcion', '$project_id', '$user_id')";
}

if (!empty($row_data)) {
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO workteam (name, description, project_id, user_id) VALUES '.implode(',', $row_data);
}
```

Así los esta guardado en la base de datos, se observa en el campo project_id que todos son iguales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como guardas los valores de `user_id` y `project_id`?

Comment: No entendí la pregunta, si vez el script los tomo con un $_POST y cargo el array y luego los guardo en el INSERT

Comment: Por favor muestra un `print_r($_POST);` a ver si se logra entender un poco qué es lo que quieres hacer. Parecería que hay una solución más simple que un doble `for`.... en el cual haces unas operaciones algo confusas. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer con los datos que vienen en el POST, cómo vienen esos datos?

Comment: Exacto, el problema es el doble `for`.  Por cada iteracion del primer for, iteras todo el array de `project_id`, por lo que la variable siempre se va a quedar con el ultimo valor del array.